# Is there a way to get the average color of a photo or get the color at certain coordinates in a photo in InDesign using ExtendScript

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I have an InDesign script which places a photo in a document and then puts some text over it. The photo can be either dark or light, so the text should be either black or white. For this to work I need my script to be able to get the information about the colors in this photo. Is there a way to get this information using ID's ExtendScript?

Comment: No i dont think theres no direct querry for either of those. But obviously it can call uppon photoshop or say imagemagick to do this for you.

Comment: It should be possible to use ExtendScript to: open the image in Photoshop, flatten the image, apply average blur, pick the first pixel in the image, decide whether you regard that pixel as dark or light and then use that variable in your InDesign script.

Comment: External program (like PS or imagemagick) is certainly an option, but it can be quite slow. It's a pity that while ID itself has Object/Extract from image/Color themes which could potentially do the trick, I found no way to use it from a script.